# 80s TV movie ending with a coffin burying a man

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I remember seeing  a TV movie (probably in the late 80s early 90s) that ended with a man climbing into a coffin with money, the coffin closes and rolls outside and buries itself.

Anyone know the name ?

Comment: Can you describe the fantasy elements more clearly? What caused the coffin to roll on its own? How did it bury itself?

Comment: What Valorum said, to help, here's a little [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to make it a bit easier to see.

Comment: Was it a series show? This sounds like a monty python sketch lol.

Comment: Also sounds a bit like the kind of twist ending you might see on something like a Tales from the Crypt anthology show, person crawls into coffin full of money they did some dastardly thing to get, winds up getting buried alive in it, cut to cryptkeeper making some joke about it.

Comment: *My* answer has fantasy elements...

Answer (score 14):

"Ray Bradbury Theater"(1985-1992 TV series)?

This sounds like episode 9 from season 3, called The Coffin. The full episode from YouTube is below.

From [this site's summary](http://genresnaps.com/ray-bradbury-theater-the-coffin-s2e9/):

> Dan O’Herlihy is inventor Charles Braling.  He has taken all his valuables out of the bank and is storing them in his home over his lawyer’s objections.  His brother Elliott has stopped by to borrow a few pounds as he apparently does on a regular basis.  Braling tells him he is dying, and is building his own coffin.  For some reason it is 9 feet long and has a window and a tape player.

....

> Elliott deduces that the fortune is hidden in the coffin.  As he climbs in to retrieve the goodies, the lid snaps shut.  Braling’s robot servants serve as pallbearers, in a well-directed scene.  You don’t see much, but you do see enough to accept that these robots actually are moving the coffin, negotiating the stairs, heading into the woods, and lowering the box.  The sequence is especially credible, paying off a previous scene where we saw Braling pacing off distances and noting directions — now we know it was for the ‘bots to follow to the grave-site.

Comment: Denholm Elliot is awesome.

Comment: You might want to find a different video since this one broke.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I'm sure this *must* be my favourite movie of all time, [The Guy with Secret Kung Fu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guy_with_the_Secret_Kung_Fu) from 1981.

The movie indeed ends with:

> A man dying as a result of entering a coffin...??

You can see the scene (and indeed the entire film) in the video below

Comment: Makes me wish I had enough reputation here to downvote, but seriously, did you read the question?

Comment: This is a great answer - but for another question...

Comment: Why downvote? Any answer is basically a guess when the question is *"what's this movie that only I can see in my head, sometime from maybe '85 to '95 but that might not be accurate"*. Upvoting the right answer would be appropriate. This is just another guess, and if it's not the right move that's useful too since you learn the "right" movie's apparently not about kung-fu. Downvoting an honest attempt to answer a vauge question is bad form